# Adding custom language to the iOS app

Tags: ios, localization, nsuserdefaults

I need to add a custom language (iOS has no localisation for it) among with support languages. A user is able to choose desired language in app settings (built-in screen, no in Settings app). I store it to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"lv"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Next time, when the app starts, it loads with selected language. And works great.

But here is a 'small' issue. The app needs to be restarted. Thus, I need a way to quit the app.

I don't want to add `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `Info.plist`, because usually the user won't switch languages, thus, I want the app typically goes to background and resumes, when a user comes back.

I know, I am not allowed to kill the process with `exit()`. Thus, I imagine maybe it is possible to set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` at runtime? Scenarios will be similar to this:
A user sets desired language and confirms it.
The app sets `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` (or do something similar to it).
The app instructs a user to quit the app by pressing Home button.

Of course, I may instruct a user to quit the app, by killing the process (go to Home screen, double click Home button, tap and hold an app icon, tap the minus). But it looks to complicated and annoying.

Maybe you have another suggestions, how to add to an app ability to switch languages?

Comment: Just display a UIAlertView telling the user to kill the app for the new language to take effect.  I know it's not the best. But it works.

Comment: Killing app on iOS 4.x is very inconvenient action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieve in-app language switch by implementing my own string bundle.

Source is available here: https://github.com/amjaliks/ObjCAdditions/tree/master/Source/Classes