# How to add an unsupported interface language to my iPhone app?

Tags: swift, localization

I have an iPhone app with interface languages in Toki Pona and Dothraki, which do not have ISO 639-3 codes. According to the ISO 639-3 standard, you can use the range qaa-qtz to represent languages for local use, which I have done (Toki Pona = qtp, Dothraki = qdt), but still get the warning from XCode "Unrecognized Locale".

It seems like I might be able to extend the main bundle class, but looking over the documentation, nothing seems to relate to adding non-ISO languages. I'm also aware of the text "If necessary, you can use a language or locale code that is not known to the NSBundle class or Core Foundation bundle functions. For example, you could create your own language designators for a language that is not yet listed in the ISO conventions or available as a language in Xcode." at the end of https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html

In any case, I mostly want to get rid of this warning. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show the code where you added locale?

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.swift.org/t/proposal-ns-locale-identifiers-etc-should-have-custom-types/9367/8

have a look at the above link.
Check if the languages are added as Localizations

[image: Have you added the languages here??]

I believe I have a solution however slightly complicated one. You would need to create a setting option within the app to use those made up languages and to load them manually from a file when a user sets them. For example, let's say your app consists of one label and the user sets the option to the made-up language you would call a method to set the language and the text on that label would update accordingly. I don't know whether this makes sense to you?? Basically, if the user uses the made-up languages that would override any system localization they have. It is doable it would just take time to implement it.

Comment: No, they don't have localizations, because they are conlangs, which don't have ISO codes. We have over 40 interface languages already in the project, so I know it's not a problem with the code. In reality, I'm not even sure adding languages without ISO codes to an iOS project is even possible.

Comment: altought this is objective C but this guy gas achieved it a long while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344906/adding-custom-language-to-the-ios-app

Comment: Have a look on my answer I have provided you with an update